# Argument Matching Python

Tags: python

Let say I have a function

```
def my_func(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c
```

I can only call it via a string:

```
eval("my_func")
```

Assuming I have a dictionary of corresponding parameters:

```
parm = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
```

How do I pass it in to `eval("my_func")`? I know that you can do it like:

```
eval("my_func")(parm['a'],parm['b'],parm['c'])
```

But if this is not a general solution since when the function changes (ie a function that has 2 parmeters as oppose to 3) it wont work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps call it with `**parm`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python

Comment: `eval("my_func")(**parm)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have commented, this is what you want:

```
>>> eval("my_func")(**parm)
6
```